# how manipulating the coefficients vector effects on the result of DFT?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

given:

[image]

calculate:

[image]

note that the given DFT is from **n** order and we want to compute DFT's from **2n** order.

edit: this is my try of B. i don't see where the given DFT is used and how to proceed:
[image]

thanks.

Comment: Apply the definition of DFT and solve the equations that will appear.

Comment: i tried but i am to confused....

Comment: Can you show us your work so we can give you hints?

Comment: i uploaded my try of B . thanks.